# How to draw this type of text in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I use DrawContext to draw text in WPF Canvas. I want the text to have this effect when it is highlighted, with red fluorescence around it. How can I achieve this? Please note that the numbers 3 and 8 are also red inside.

[image: Image is HERE]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-outlined-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8